# Не удается спозиционировать картинки внутри блоков

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, позиционирование

Всем привет. Есть одинаковые блоки с разными по размеру иконками. Мне нужно добиться того, чтобы все иконки располагались по центру как горизонтально, так и вертикально. Столкнулся с тем, что стандартный подход `dispaly:table-cell; vertical-align:middle` здесь не срабатывает. создавать отдельные id и заниматься абсолютным позиционированием для каждого не выйдет -  иконки могут меняться. как же быть?

```css
.product-category {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #979567;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.product-category img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<a class="product-category" href="#">
  <img src="http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/nuvola2/32x32/3floppy_unmount.png">
</a>
<a class="product-category" href="#">
  <img src="http://forum.ucoz.ru/img/camera_test.png">
</a>
<a class="product-category" href="#">
  <img src="http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/0912/MedICOFreeMedicalIcons/w64h641347633749nuclear.png">
</a>
<a class="product-category" href="#">
  <img src="http://corel.demiart.ru/preview/ussr_prev.gif">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё много проще:

```css
span.table {
  display: table;
}
a.product-category {
  background-color: #979567;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
 <span class="table">
     <a class="product-category" href="#">
       <img src="http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/nuvola2/32x32/3floppy_unmount.png">
     </a>
     <a class="product-category" href="#">
       <img src="http://forum.ucoz.ru/img/camera_test.png">
     </a>
     <a class="product-category" href="#">
       <img src="http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/0912/MedICOFreeMedicalIcons/w64h641347633749nuclear.png">
     </a>
     <a class="product-category" href="#">
       <img src="http://corel.demiart.ru/preview/ussr_prev.gif">
     </a>
    </span>
```

Как бы мне теперь развидеть результат?!

Answer (score 1):

необходимо  `.product-category` добавить 
`line-height: 200px` + `display: block` or `display: inline-block;`

Пример

```css
.product-category {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;    
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #979567;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.product-category img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<a class="product-category" href="#">
  <img src="http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/nuvola2/32x32/3floppy_unmount.png">
</a>

<a class="product-category" href="#">
  <img src="http://forum.ucoz.ru/img/camera_test.png">
</a>

<a class="product-category" href="#">
  <img src="http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/0912/MedICOFreeMedicalIcons/w64h641347633749nuclear.png">
</a>

<a class="product-category" href="#">
  <img src="http://corel.demiart.ru/preview/ussr_prev.gif">
</a>
```

Вариант 2

```css
.product-category {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;      
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #979567;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.product-category img {
    position: relative; top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<a class="product-category" href="#">
  <img src="http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/nuvola2/32x32/3floppy_unmount.png">
</a>

<a class="product-category" href="#">
  <img src="http://forum.ucoz.ru/img/camera_test.png">
</a>

<a class="product-category" href="#">
  <img src="http://s1.iconbird.com/ico/0912/MedICOFreeMedicalIcons/w64h641347633749nuclear.png">
</a>

<a class="product-category" href="#">
  <img src="http://corel.demiart.ru/preview/ussr_prev.gif">
</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/fodwb163/

http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/eetfrkvj/

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто иконки положить как бэкграунд и задать ему background-position: center;

Comment: не @ГенераторКачества, автоматизировать не получится. иконки с админки подтягиваются, которые изменять можно, так что бэкграунд здесь не вариант